# How to change static string value by another class?

Tags: c#, string, static, connection-string

I have class **DatabaseObjects** which have public static string fields. I have a `filename` and `ConnectionStringExcel` in this class. Code is as-

```
class DatabaseObjects
{
    public static string filename = "";
    public static string ConnectionStringExcel = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                                       filename + "; Extended Properties= 'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'";
}
```

I want to set the `filename` by the `OpenDialogBox` in **frmStudents** class on button **Import** Click event. And this `filename` given by user should be added to the `ConnectionStringExcel`(Which is in other class).

Code of **frmStudents** Class

```
 public partial class frmStudents : Form
{
private void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileExcel = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileExcel.Filter = "Excel Files | *.xlsx; *.xls; *.xlsm";
        openFileExcel.Title = "Select an Excel File";
        if (openFileExcel.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel || openFileExcel.FileName.Equals(""))
            return;
        DatabaseObjects.filename = openFileExcel.FileName;
        using(OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(DatabaseObjects.ConnectionStringExcel))
        {
            string queryExcel = "SELECT * FROM [Six$]";
            using (OleDbCommand commandExcel = new OleDbCommand(queryExcel,connExcel))
            {
                connExcel.Open();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the user select the file in `OpenDialogBox`,  the `filename` string get the value correctly. But `filename` string value is not combining in `ConnectionStringExcel`. The `Data Source` value remains empty. How to resolve this?

If I remove `static` keyword from `filename` and `ConnectionStringExcel`, it is giving error that **filename** `A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field`. What now?

Comment: Having a public fields is bad approach, make sense to convert `fileName` to property

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski i have convert it to Property. But still same error.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using to compile this code?

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 version

Comment: The problem in your current code is caused (as by the answer from Redi below) by the static nature of the ConnectionStringExcel property that once initialized is never updated. But the solution proposed could not work with Visual Studio 2013. _Support for expression body definitions was introduced for methods and read-only properties in C# 6 and was expanded in C# 7.0._ Then create a normal property get for ConnectionStringExcel

Comment: Second thought. Time to upgrade to Visual Studio 2019. Community version is free.

Comment: @Steve I have the change the `filename` and `ConnectionStringExcel` to  normal string field. Now it is given error before compiling that **filename** `A field initializer cannot reference the non - static field `.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConnectionStringExcel` is **initialized** using `filename` but it won't track future changes.

You can convert `ConnectionStringExcel` into a readonly property with this getter

```
public static string ConnectionStringExcel => @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                                       filename + "; Extended Properties= 'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'";
```

This will cause the string to be constructed with every call to `ConnectionStringExcel`

**EDIT**

If you're using an old version of the .net framework you can use

```
public static string ConnectionStringExcel 
{
   get 
   { 
      return @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                                       filename + "; Extended Properties= 'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'"; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Now it is giving error before compiling, `filename` is `field` but is used like `type`.

Comment: It seems that OP is using Visual Studio 2013. Probably expression body definitions don't work with that version of the C# compiler. Workaround, normal get property.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to build the `GetConnectionStringExcel`. Also, I recommend you to use the `CheckFileExists` in `OpenFileDialog` object, it will check if the selected file exist. Here is a code snip.

```
public static class DatabaseObjects
{
    public static string FileName;

    public static string GetConnectionStringExcel()
    {
        return GetConnectionStringExcel(FileName);
    }

    public static string GetConnectionStringExcel(string filename)
    {
        return @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
               filename + "; Extended Properties= 'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'";
    }
}

public partial class frmStudents : Form
{
    private void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var openFileExcel = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            Filter = "Excel Files | *.xlsx; *.xls; *.xlsm",
            Title = "Select an Excel File",
            CheckFileExists = true
        };
        if (openFileExcel.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
            return;

        DatabaseObjects.FileName = openFileExcel.FileName;
        using (var connExcel = new OleDbConnection(DatabaseObjects.GetConnectionStringExcel()))
        {
            string queryExcel = "SELECT * FROM [Six$]";
            using (var commandExcel = new OleDbCommand(queryExcel, connExcel))
            {
                connExcel.Open();
            }
        }
    }
}
```